# I need to display post related info

Tags: customization, permalinks

WordPress CPT URLs are displayed at this format: www.example.com/cpt/post-slug.

I need to have URL like this www.example.com/cpt/post-slug/rating that will include rating details for corresponding post-slug.

For example:

www.example.com/cpt/harry-potter/rating will display rating details for 'harry-potter' and www.example.com/cpt/abcdefgh/rating will display rating details for 'abcdefgh'

I don't know what to name this functionality or how to do it :(

Would you please share some opinion with me?

--code for cpt named 'lessons'--

```
function register_lesson_init() {

    $labels = array(
            'name'                => _x( 'Lessons', 'Lessons', 'text_domain' ),
            'singular_name'       => _x( 'Lesson', 'Lesson', 'text_domain' ),
            'menu_name'           => __( 'Lessons', 'text_domain' ),
            'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
            'all_items'           => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
            'view_item'           => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
            'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
            'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
            'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
            'update_item'         => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
            'search_items'        => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
            'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
            'label'               => __( 'Lessons', 'text_domain' ),
            'description'         => __( 'Lessons Description', 'text_domain' ),
            'labels'              => $labels,
            'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'revisions', 'post-formats'),
            'taxonomies'          => array( 'es-lesson-topic' ),
            'hierarchical'        => true,
            'public'              => true,
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_in_menu'        => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
            'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
            'menu_position'       => 5,
            'menu_icon'           => '',
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'es-lesson', $args );}
```

i need to display related question page for this cpt
url will look like: www.example.com/lessons/post-slug/question and I don't khow how to :(

Comment: Would you please share some code with us. Without code you making it very difficult for someone to help you

Comment: I have added my codings for cpt :)

Answer (score 0):

I fear you will struggle to do this, as you will need to utilise rewrite rules in a "sensitive" area; custom post types.

Could you not change your thinking slightly, and do it like so?

```
www.example.com/questions/post-slug/
www.example.com/ratings/post-slug/
etc...
```

Comment: yep ;-) thanks for your suggestion. is there no way to do as I like to do?

Comment: I'm unsure, to be honest. Unless you use push states?